# Call to undefined function PHP error

Tags: php

Esta es la linea que me da error

```
$sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentitites($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\'';
```

El error es este

> [03-Mar-2019 19:54:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   function htmlentitites() in censurado/api_managecredentials.php on
>   line 25

Answer (score 1):

El error es que el nombre de la funcion es 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

no `htmlentitites`. Te sobra una T al final.